# C++ переопределение виртуальной функции

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, виртуальная-функция

Прочёл что при создании `virtual void foo(){};` даст возможность переопределять функции в дочерних классах, но этого не случается

GameObject.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

namespace snake{
    class GameObject : public sf::RectangleShape{
    public:
        GameObject();

        std::string name;

        virtual void logic();
        void setObjectTexture(std::string texturePath);

    private:
        sf::Texture *textureObject;
        void setup();
    };
}
```

Его логика

```
void GameObject::logic(){
    std::cout << "old logic" << std::endl;
}
```

Button.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include "Snake/GameObject.hpp"
#include "iostream"

namespace Ui{
    class Button : public virtual snake::GameObject{
    public:
        void logic();

    private:
        void setup();
    };
}
```

Его логика

```
void Button::logic() {
    std::cout << "new logic" << std::endl;
}
```

Однако при вызове функции из другого класса(Объект класса Button уже лежит в векторе gameObjects)

```
void Scene::logicObjects(){
    for (int i = 0; i != gameObjects.size(); i++)
        gameObjects[i].logic();
}
```

Я вижу вывод в консоль *old logic*, хотя казалось бы, переопределил функцию. Что пошло не так и почему не срабатывает переопределение функции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, у вас вектор такой?

```
vector<snake::GameObject> gameObjects;
```

Тогда при внесении в него объектов, производных от `snake::GameObject`, происходит их [*срезка*](https://ravesli.com/urok-170-obrezka-obektov/) до `snake::GameObject`, и, соответственно, вызывается `logic()` для этого типа.

Вот если бы вы работали с `vector<snake::GameObject*>`...